# Возможно ли сделать внутреннюю страницу и открывать ее с подомена, Wordpress?

Tags: wordpress

Есть сайт на WordPress
Создал внутреннюю страницу с калькулятором по адрессу site.ru/calculator
Можно ли сделать что бы то что отображается на этой странице открывалось на поддомене. К примеру calculator.site.ru , или же требуется для поддомена грузить свою CMS

Comment: https://wordpress.org/plugins/page-as-subdomain-lite/ и тп

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Сделать это можно путём настройки хостинга, поддомена и несложной манипуляцией с темой WordPress.

- Направляете поддомен на главную страницу;
- Создаёте страницу с постоянной ссылкой, которая соответствует имени поддомена;
- Добавляете обработку URL в `functions.php` Вашей темы.

  ```
  <?php

  function hijack_page() {     
  // делим URL и проверяем, является ли первая часть поддоменом.
  $pieces = explode( '.', $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] );
  $subdomain = array_shift( $pieces ); // получаем первую часть разделенного URL

  // получаем адрес страницы после домена
  $pieces = explode('/', $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
  array_shift($pieces);
  $slug1 = array_shift($pieces); // получаем первую часть окончания URI страницы

  // Проверяем, существует ли страница и отличается ли поддомен от "www"
  if($slug1 && $subdomain != "www"){

         // получаем основные переменные запроса WP query 
         // для получение содержимого страницы
         global $query_string;     
         // выполняем запрос the query posts чтобы получить желаемую страницу
         query_posts($query_string.'&pagename='.$subdomain.'/'.$slug1);
         return;
      }
  }     
  hijack_page();
  ?>
  ```

Источник: https://www.yhunter.ru/blog/news/poddomeny-i-wordpress-bez-plagina/

Как альтернативный вариант, можно поискать какие-нибудь плагины для работы с поддоменами.

Comment: Спасибо большое